# Why does the bloc extension for VScode does not generate code that extends Equatable?

Tags: flutter, vscode-extensions, bloc, state-management

I've been following [Reso Coder bloc tutorial](https://youtu.be/nQMfaQeCL6M?list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4jCBkrirvVGr5b8rC95VAQ5&t=230)
And he is using Fleix Angelov [bloc extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FelixAngelov.bloc) for VScode.

As you can see when Reso genrates use Bloc: new bloc -
[image]

He gets prompted with 2 forms -

1 - Bloc Name

[image]

2 - Would you like to use the Equatable package ?

[image]

But as you can see the extension was changed and you are **only prompted for the name** -

[bloc VScode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FelixAngelov.bloc)

**Also instead of 4 files only 3 are generated.**

Does anyone know why the extension was changed to act like so (To not extend Equatable) and also why one of the files (The export one is not generated anymore) ?

Comment: Just tried it and for me the event and the state class extend Equatable. There are only 3 files but that's fine since they use the part and part of stuff which means you only have to import your xyz_bloc.dart file to have access to everything.

Comment: You sure you have the latest version of the extension ? On the demo there's no Equatable extension.

Comment: Yes, its from 16.12.2021 which seems to be the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Add `"bloc.newBlocTemplate.type": "equatable"` to your `.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

If not getting option for creating new Bloc when right clicking on the folder , then press :-

```
Ctrl + shift + p
```

and then select the following option from drop down menu :-

```
Bloc: New Bloc
```

then select the folder in which to create the Bloc folder
and thus the Bloc folder will be created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

add dependencies in pubspec.yaml it's work for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqSYO.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).